# Jenkins Jelly f:property propertyDescriptor attribute

Tags: jenkins, jelly, propertydescriptor

I am having some trouble using Jenkins property.jelly propertyDescriptor field. After doing some research, I found the propertyDescriptor attribute implementation is confusing.

Here is the code:

[property.jelly file](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/lib/form/property.jelly)

See this line:

```html
<j:set var="descriptor" value="${attrs.propertyDescriptor ?: app.getDescriptorOrDie(descriptor.getPropertyTypeOrDie(instance,field).clazz)}" />
```

I assume that ?: is the ternary operator in Jelly? However, it essentially says: 
if ${attrs.propertyDescriptor} is set, set "descriptor" to nothing, otherwise
set "descriptor" to app.getDescriptorOrDie( ... )

Shouldn't it be:

```html
<j:set var="descriptor" value="${attrs.propertyDescriptor ? ${attrs.propertyDescriptor : app.getDescriptorOrDie(descriptor.getPropertyTypeOrDie(instance,field).clazz)}" />
```

Note the code I inserted between ? and :.

Is this a bug in property.jelly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got the answer, it's called 
[Elvis operator](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/operators.html)